# Having problems selecting values from a <select> to put into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code. I am attempting to get values from the drop down menu and text, put them into the equation. What am I doing wrong so that the function is stopping half way through. I know it is probably really easy to solve but I cannot find a solution anywhere. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> Question 6 </h3>
        <h4> How long can you safely tan for? </h4>
        <script language="javascript">
            function calculate5() {
                var skin = document.getElementById("skinselect");
                var skinselect = Math.floor(skinselect.options[skinselect.selectedIndex].value);
                var cloud = document.getElementById("cloudselect");
                var cloudselect = Math.floor(cloudselect.options[cloudselect.selectedIndex].value);
                var temp = Math.floor(document.getElementById("temp").value);
                var time = ((skinselect + cloudselect) * temp) - 50;
                alert("Your safe sunbaking time is " + time + " minutes");
            }
        </script>
        <select id="skinselect">
            <option value="error">Skin type: 0 is light, 5 is dark </option>
            <option value="0"> 0 </option>
            <option value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> 2 </option>
            <option value="3"> 3 </option>
            <option value="4"> 4 </option>
            <option value="5"> 5 </option>
        </select>
        <select id="cloudselect">
            <option value="error">Cloud Cover: 0 is clear, 5 is overcast </option>
            <option value="0"> 0 </option>
            <option value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> 2 </option>
            <option value="3"> 3 </option>
            <option value="4"> 4 </option>
            <option value="5"> 5 </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" value="Temperature (C)" id="temp" size="16">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate5()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your function you need to access option from select id

```
var skin = document.getElementById("skinselect");
var skinselect = Math.floor(skin.options[skin.selectedIndex].value);
var cloud = document.getElementById("cloudselect");
var cloudselect = Math.floor(cloud.options[cloud.selectedIndex].value);
var temp = Math.floor(document.getElementById("temp").value);
var time = ((skinselect + cloudselect) * temp) - 50;
```

you can refer
[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
var skinselect = Math.floor(skin.options[skin.selectedIndex].value);
```

and

```
var cloudselect = Math.floor(cloud.options[cloud.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("skinselect").value contains its selected option value. 
Set a default value in case any option hasn't already been selected. 
Eg.
      `<select id="skinselect" value="error">` 
(because error is the default value due to the fact it's on the top of the options list)